# location.href load on the current page/previous url

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following jquery for onclick code :

```
function find(){
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: link + 'register/data',
    data: {},
    success: function () {
        window.location.href= "mycontroller/myfunction"
    }
});
```

}

i want to make the url stays on mycontroller/myfunction everytime they click the button, i tried substring lastindexof but it keeps adding more url everytime i click the button, how do i make the button stays on that whenever i click it?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's pretend you're on `http://example.com`. You redirect the page to `"test"`, so now you're on `http://example.com/test`. Now you redirect to `"test"` again. Uh oh, now you're on `http://example.com/test/test`. Didn't want that to happen, did you? You redirect it just one more time to `"other/test"`. Oh no, now you're on `http://example.com/test/test/other/test`!

The way to solve this resides in a single bytes. Change `test` to `/test`, so it'll always compare to the base URL instead of the current one.

In your JavaScript:

```js
window.location.href = "/mycontroller/myfunction";
```

However you click it you'll always be on `http://example.com/mycontroller/myfunction`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the success function to use `window.location.origin` like this:

```
function find(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: link + 'register/data',
    data: {},
    success: function () {
        window.location.href = window.location.origin + "/mycontroller/myfunction"
    }
  });
}
```